# Error #1109 - unknown table in field list caused by trigger

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

This is my trigger.

I want to make trigger on 1 table (pelayanan).

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `before_insert_pelayanan` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `pelayanan` FOR EACH ROW 
IF NEW.`ESTIMASI` IS NULL OR NEW.`ESTIMASI` = 0 AND
    `dbhpl`.`pelayanan`.`DAYA` <= 5500 
    THEN SET NEW.ESTIMASI = 4; 
ELSEIF NEW.ESTIMASI IS NULL OR NEW.ESTIMASI = 0 AND
    `dbhpl`.`pelayanan`.`DAYA` <= 33000 AND 
    `dbhpl`.`pelayanan`.`DAYA` >= 6600 
    THEN SET NEW.ESTIMASI = 15; 
ELSEIF NEW.ESTIMASI IS NULL OR NEW.ESTIMASI = 0 AND
   `dbhpl`.`pelayanan`.`DAYA` <= 197000 AND 
   `dbhpl`.`pelayanan`.`DAYA` >= 41500 
    THEN SET NEW.ESTIMASI = 40; 
ELSE SET NEW.ESTIMASI = 100; 
END IF
```

When I execute the trigger, it has been created. But, when I insert data into table pelayanan, It become

> #1109 - Unknown table 'pelayanan' in field list.

How can I resolve this?

I have to remove `dbhpl.pelayanan.DAYA` become `pelayanan.DAYA` and `DAYA`. But, It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use NEW before column name. This is the right code-

```
mysql>
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `before_insert_pelayanan`
    BEFORE INSERT ON `pelayanan` FOR EACH ROW 
        IF NEW.`ESTIMASI` IS NULL OR NEW.`ESTIMASI` = 0 AND
            `NEW`.`DAYA` <= 5500 
            THEN SET NEW.ESTIMASI = 4; 
        ELSEIF NEW.ESTIMASI IS NULL OR NEW.ESTIMASI = 0 AND
            `NEW`.`DAYA` <= 33000 AND 
            `NEW`.`DAYA` >= 6600 
            THEN SET NEW.ESTIMASI = 15; 
        ELSEIF NEW.ESTIMASI IS NULL OR NEW.ESTIMASI = 0 AND
           `NEW`.`DAYA` <= 197000 AND 
           `NEW`.`DAYA` >= 41500 
            THEN SET NEW.ESTIMASI = 40; 
        ELSE SET NEW.ESTIMASI = 100; 
    END IF

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.11 sec)

mysql> insert into pelayanan values ();
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> select * from pelayanan ;
+----------+------+
| ESTIMASI | daya |
+----------+------+
| 4        | NULL |
+----------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: thanks. It works on my database. But I have to change "ELSE IF" with "IF". Because, if I use ELSE IF, the result of execution just become "4" for all data. NOT 15, 40, and, 100.