# MySQL Trigger Issue with that specific problem

Tags: mysql

> Galaxy Airlines is a newly launched airlines service that operates
> flights to and from various cities all over Europe. To enable faster
> and efficient performance, galaxy Airlines has decided to incorporate
> use of triggers in their database applications.

The detailed list of operations to be performed are as follows:

a) **Create the following tables (Flight and Flight_Details) in GalaxyAirlines
database:**
[Image Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10y1S.png)

my code:

```
CREATE TABLE FLIGHT(AIRCRAFT_CODE VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY, SOURC VARCHAR(20), DESTINATION VARCHAR(20), DEP_TIME VARCHAR(10),JOURNEY_HOUR INT); 

CREATE TABLE FLIGHT_DET(CLASS_CODE VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY, AIRCRAFT_CODE VARCHAR(10),FOREIGN KEY(AIRCRAFT_CODE) REFERENCES FLIGHT(AIRCRAFT_CODE),FARE INT,SEAT INT);
```

*Note: Insert at least five records in each table.* (Done that Part too.

b) **Write a statement to create a trigger trgCheckSeats that will activate whenever
a new row in being inserted into the Flight_Details table. The maximum
number of seats that a flight can contain is 150. The trigger should check for
the value of seats being inserted. If it is more than 150, the INSERT operation
is not allowed to succeed.**

I'm Stuck Here

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER trgCheckSeats BEFORE INSERT ON
    FLIGHT_DET FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF FLIGHT_DET.SEAT > 150 or FLIGHT_DET.SEAT < 0 THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000';  
    END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Trigger Insertion

```
INSERT INTO FLIGHT_DET VALUES('2', "5", 424, 793);
INSERT INTO FLIGHT_DET VALUES('3', "1", 1214, 45);
INSERT INTO FLIGHT_DET VALUES('4', "4", 1310, 333);
INSERT INTO FLIGHT_DET VALUES('5', "3", 330, 34);
```

Error: `#1109 - Unknown table 'FLIGHT_DET' in field list`

c) **Write statements to create a trigger UpdateValid that will activate will a row is
being updated in the Flight_Details table. The trigger should determine if the
The seat column is present in the list of columns being updated. If yes, the
Update Operation should not succeed because the Seat column is defined
as a constant and cannot be changed**

Comment: Use the correct table name. In your trigger code you use `FLIGHT_DET`, the error message shows `FLIGHT_DETAIL` and the screenshot shows `Flight_Details`. You have to use the name of the table which actually is used in the database.

Comment: YES, I'm TRY IT NOW, BUT GETTING the SAME ERROR.

Comment: Error is not produced by published code. Check for other triggers

Comment: Try using the `new` keyword, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31178162/error-1109-unknown-table-in-field-list-caused-by-trigger